# Displaying the description of entity from kb id in spacy entity linking

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, entity-linking

> I have successfully trained a spacy entity linking model(obviously by
> limiting the data).
>
> my question is how to display the description
> of entity from kb as output?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load(r"D:\el model\nlp")
doc = nlp("Amir Khan is a great boxer")
ents = [(e.text, e.label_, e.kb_id_) for e in doc.ents]
print(ents)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by Sofie Van Landeghem(Spacy Entity Linking Representative).
The descriptions are currently not stored in the KB itself because of performance reasons. However, from the intermediary results during processing, you should have a file entity_descriptions.csv that maps the WikiData ID to its description in a simple tabular format.